# Junit-5 Test Execution Order

Tags: selenium, junit, appium, xcuitest

I am writing automation scripts to test a an iOS App on a real device. I'm using appium server. I having some issues related to Junit Test Case execution. I previously wrote 9 test methods with @order() annotation. Like 1->9 . and I put the server capabilties in the first test method. Till 9 methods the execution was going fine. But when I wrote the 10 11 and 12 method. The execution started from 10th method. As 10->11->12->1-> and so on till 9.

Here's the code

```
class TesClass {
 String appiumPort ="4723";
 String serverIp ="0.0.0.0";
 static IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver;
 LoginPage lPage=null;
 DesiredCapabilities cap;
 ProgrammesPage p_page=null;
 MainPage mPage=null;



 /*
  * Order is the priority of the test case
  * this is the first test case in this class
  * This is responsible for creating connection with the appium server
  * this sets basic capabilities and some advance capabilities 
  * to run the test cases on a real Ios device
  * 
  */
@Order(1)
@Test
void test() throws MalformedURLException  {
    cap= new DesiredCapabilities();


      cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Muhammad’s iPhone");
      cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
      cap.setCapability("platformVersion","12.1.2");
      cap.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
      cap.setCapability("app", "/Users/ahmsam/Downloads/MainApp-2.ipa");
      cap.setCapability("xcodeOrgId","BNL4VQ2576");
      cap.setCapability("xcodeSigningId","iPhone Developer");
      cap.setCapability("udid","240476512a6dd29a2f82fc8211ef4ea1bf6b5891");
     // cap.setCapability("udid","3c7ad82d510561a572d459cab855154cd578e3da");
      cap.setCapability("updateWDABundleId","5SN9XXLNWB.uk.org.humanfocus.WildCard.Dev");

      String serverUrl = "http://" + serverIp + ":" + appiumPort + "/wd/hub";
      driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL(serverUrl), cap);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(55,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      lPage=new LoginPage(driver);
      lPage.firstThreePopoClick();
      boolean check= lPage.validateLoginpage();

     // = lPage.loginTestCase();

     Assert.assertTrue(check);


     //fail("Not yet implemented");
}

 @Order(2)
 @Test
    void test1() 
    {
        lPage=new LoginPage(driver);

        boolean check1=lPage.TestdoLoginWIthValues();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1==true);

    }

 @Order(3)
 @Test
    void test3() 
    {
        lPage=new LoginPage(driver);

        boolean check1=lPage.loginTestCase();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1==true);

    }

 @Order(4)
 @Test
    void test4() 
    {
        lPage=new LoginPage(driver);

        boolean check1=lPage.TestGotoHomePage();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1==true);

    }

 @Order(5)
 @Test
    void test5() 
    {
        mPage=new MainPage(driver);


        boolean check1=mPage.goToTrainings();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1);

    }

 @Order(6)
 @Test
    void test6() 
    {
        p_page=new ProgrammesPage(driver);


        boolean check1=p_page.verifyProgramCode();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1);

    }

 @Order(7)
 @Test
    void test7() 
    {
        p_page=new ProgrammesPage(driver);
        boolean check1=p_page.verifyContinueBtnDisable();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1);

    }

 @Order(8)
 @Test
    void test8() 
    {
        p_page=new ProgrammesPage(driver);
        boolean check1=p_page.verifyVideoNextBtnDIsable();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1);

    }

 @Order(9)
 @Test
    void test9() throws InterruptedException 
    {
        p_page=new ProgrammesPage(driver);
        boolean check1=p_page.verifyWatchView_ClickonNextBtn();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1);

    }

 @Order(10)
 @Test
    void test10() 
    {
        p_page=new ProgrammesPage(driver);
        boolean check1=p_page.verifyDocumentPageNextButton();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1);

    }

 @Order(11)
 @Test
    void test11() 
    {
        p_page=new ProgrammesPage(driver);
        boolean check1=p_page.verifyViewDocument_NextBtn();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1);

    }

 @Order(12)
 @Test
    void test12() 
    {
        p_page=new ProgrammesPage(driver);
        boolean check1=p_page.verifyLastSectionName();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1);

    }
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76O5F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the @TestMethodOrder annotation to specify the desired method orderer implementation to use, in this case the OrderAnnotation.  Add this annotation to your test class: `@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)`. Like:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class TestClass {

    @Order(1)
    @Test
    void test() {
    ...
```